# Is Cassandra suitable as the main database for a social networking site?

Tags: sql, cassandra, relational-database, nosql

There's been a lot of hype about NoSQL databases being used by big sites like Twitter and Facebook.  However, as I've looked into this more carefully, it seems like most of the successful companies in this space have been using a combination of database technologies, using MySQL as the main database and then adding NoSQL databases for things like adding a caching layer to improve performance. I've also heard that Diaspora originally started out using MongoDB as their primary database, and then had to switch to a relational database because Mongo turned out to be ill-suited to their needs. In particular, I've heard that representing relationships between users really calls for a relational database or maybe a graph database.

*However*, Spotify seems to be really big on Cassandra, which is neither a relational database nor a graph database. Furthermore, while Spotify isn't known for social networking, it does include features like being able to follow other users and see what songs they've been listening to. If this is all done with Cassandra, maybe Cassandra is well-suited for social networking, even representing relationships between users? Can anyone give me any insight into this?

EDIT: I know Cassandra doesn't support joins, but is there a reasonable way to represent a social graph with Cassandra in spite of lack of joins? Also, I'm especially interested in Cassandra vs. SQL for social graph, less interested in Cassandra vs. graph DB.

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra is very good for high speed writes and reads using simple key-values, or bigtable-esque slices within a partition.

Cassandra is very bad at anything that you would model as a SQL JOIN, or searching for arbitrary text.

The reason people tend to use a combination of technologies is that different tech is designed for different problems - a tool optimized for searching (elasticsearch, solr, etc) is going to be much better at search-type problems, but won't have the read/write throughput for key/value lookups that you'll get from Cassandra.

Answer (score 1):

They all have different use cases and a single database may not suffice.

For a social networking site, a combination of these may be used. A SQL or NoSQL db may be used for storing user information, preferences, and the like, depending upon what scale you're looking at.

Relationship requirements (social network) are however different, and both SQL and NoSQL databases (including Cassandra) would be a bad choice to represent these.

A graph database tends to be an order of magnitude faster and efficient in representing a social graph and executing related algorithms.

Comment: That's interesting about graph databases. I'd heard about them, but didn't know they were that much better for social graph stuff. Still if you had to choose relational vs. Cassandra for social graph, what would you choose?

Comment: There exist graph DBs that run on cassandra - titan being perhaps the most common. That gives you the linear scalability at the storage layer of Cassandra, with the access characteristics of Titan/Gremlin/graph. 

Worth noting, of course, that the fact that a graph db can be written on Cassandra means that you could certainly do it yourself, if you were so inclined.

Comment: For the specific use case of storing social graph, neo4j (http://neo4j.com) is one of the most popular graph databases.